# How to define "n" as any natural cardinal number variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, numbers

So I have always wanted to do something like this, but never knew how to use an undefined natural variable (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...)

I want something like this:

```
if($("#container").width() == 400*n) {
  //do something
}
```

In which case n can be any natural cardinal number (and preferably not zero). How do you define `n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript does not solve equations with unknowns for you; at any given time, a variable always holds a specific value.

So, what you seem to want to do (if I understand your question correctly) is not possible. Instead, you need to solve the equation you gave yourself:

```
$("#container").width() == 400 * n
```

can be restated as

```
$("#container").width() / 400 == n
```

Now, since you require `n` to be an integer, the above statement means that dividing `$("#container").width()` will yield a whole number. The requirement "dividing *a* by *x* yields a whole number" is usually expressed with the modulo operator (`%` in JavaScript) as `a % x == 0`. Thus you end up with:

```
$("#container").width() % 400 == 0
```

Answer (score 6):

The perfect place for the [Modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator

```
if ($("#container").width() % 400 === 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This evaluates to true if the width is an exact multiple of 400 (0, 400, 800, 1200, 1600, ...).